# Org Mode source block not highlighted

Tags: org-mode

Okay, so I just observed a weird thing with my org document. The source blocks are fine if I go from top to bottom, however, when I directly jump to bottom and then move towards the top, the source blocks don't get highlighted untill the languge name of the source block comes in the visible buffer. Like in the image:

[image]

They do stay highlighted after being highlighted once though, so I was just wondering if this is a bug or that's just how it is? It's not really a huge problem but I would like to fix it if possible as it is a little annoying in files where I have a little bugger source blocks like my qtile config.

I am Using emacs version: 27.0.91